# Discord js audit logs events optional information

Tags: events, discord.js, audit

I have a thought: I want to create a system that will respond to events and report this to a separate moderator chat. Delete / update channel. Modify / delete message and so on. I already made some of them and they work.

But I do not understand. I want to create an event that would respond to a change in the channel (or role). For example: in the channel, the hierarchy of roles has changed, or some rule for a certain role has been added. And I don’t understand how I can bring this information to the channel using audit.

Here is the "channelUpdate" code:

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { purple_light } = require("../../colours.json")

module.exports = (bot, oldChannel, newChannel) => {

    const logChannel = oldChannel.guild.channels.find(c => c.id === "687260937744416798"); // channel-log-id

    if (oldChannel === newChannel || !logChannel) return;
    oldChannel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 11, limit: 1 })
        .then(audit => {
            let user = audit.entries.first().executor;
            let opt = audit.entries.first().extra;

            let logEmbed = new RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`Channel was update: | ${oldChannel.name}`)
                .addField("Now:", `${newChannel.name}`)
                .addField("Channel id:", `${newChannel.id}`)
                .addField("Updated by:", `${user}`)
                .addField("Changes:", `${opt}`)
                .setColor(purple_light)
                .setTimestamp();
            logChannel.send(logEmbed).catch(() => console.error);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}
```

Can someone tell me in which direction to move or maybe where to look for information on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For channel permission you need handle another [event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AuditLogAction)

> CHANNEL_OVERWRITE_CREATE: 13
>
> CHANNEL_OVERWRITE_DELETE: 15
>
> CHANNEL_OVERWRITE_UPDATE: 14

Then you can get [changes](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AuditLogChange), map values and get change info.  For roles you need handle event role update, and get changes like in my solution.

```js
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { purple_light } = require("../../colours.json")

module.exports = (bot, oldChannel, newChannel) => {

    const logChannel = oldChannel.guild.channels.find(c => c.id === "687260937744416798"); // channel-log-id
    //event for permission 
    //  CHANNEL_OVERWRITE_CREATE: 13
    //  CHANNEL_OVERWRITE_UPDATE: 14
    //  CHANNEL_OVERWRITE_DELETE: 15
    //event for permissions
    if (oldChannel === newChannel || !logChannel) return;
    oldChannel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 13, limit: 1 })
        .then(audit => {
            let user = audit.entries.first().executor;
            let opt = audit.entries.first().extra;
            let changes = audit.entries.first().changes
            let changedValues = changes.map(c => `${c.key} is changet from ${c.old} to ${c.new}`).join('\n')
            console.log(changedValues)
            let logEmbed = new RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`Channel was update: | ${oldChannel.name}`)
                .addField("Now:", `${newChannel.name}`)
                .addField("Channel id:", `${newChannel.id}`)
                .addField("Updated by:", `${user}`)
                .addField("Changes:", `${opt}`)
                .setColor(purple_light)
                .setTimestamp();
            logChannel.send(logEmbed).catch(() => console.error);
        })
        .catch(console.error);


}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!

I pointed out the code exactly as you wrote, but something went wrong.

When i changed some channel role permission i get the following on output in the console:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14CH-BzFZlU7JUBdkvdUf60iJbIM64erT/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z0CPbkdrGhxiYVjZHTFlAa8xZnLP1H_d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmm, so the other way its check permission before, than permission after and compare it :/

Comment: hm... my Bot has all Administrator rights. And in the console there is no corresponding error about lack of authority.

Okay, thanks, and on that, you helped me a lot. I will try to find a solution.

Comment: Hello again. Sorry for asking for help again, but I still could not solve my problem. The bot seems to be responding to the event, but does not report what exactly has been changed in the channel.
You wrote that you may need to add an permissions check event. How can i do this? Bot currently has all Administrator rights and therefore I do not know how to add verification.

Comment: @Sorrow You need to compare permissions collection. I have thoughts on how this can be done with regard to permissions, but it seems to me that this will not be a completely “clean” option.

Comment: oh, it sounds like I understand what it is about (sarcasm). It's complicated.
Okay. Thank you for trying and for the time you spent. I will try to do something, or I will return to this later. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this will be costly, I hope I could help you at least a little

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`channelUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelUpdate), [`messageUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageUpdate), [`roleUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-roleUpdate) etc. events on `Client`.

```js
client.on("channelUpdate", (oldChannel, newChannel) => {
    const logChannel = oldChannel.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === "687260937744416798"); // channel-log-id

    if (oldChannel === newChannel || !logChannel) return;
    oldChannel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: 11, limit: 1})
        .then(audit => {
            const user = audit.entries.first().executor;
            const opt = audit.entries.first().extra;

            const logEmbed = new RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`Channel was update: | ${oldChannel.name}`)
                .addField("Now:", `${newChannel.name}`)
                .addField("Channel id:", `${newChannel.id}`)
                .addField("Updated by:", `${user}`)
                .addField("Changes:", `${opt}`)
                .setColor(purple_light)
                .setTimestamp();
            logChannel.send(logEmbed).catch(console.error);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.
Unfortunately this method did not help me. The bot does not respond to the event. Even if I just change the name of the channel. But thanks anyway for the help.